# Drawing a circle using a PointF as its center c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, draw, picturebox, geometry

I was searching for this but I couldnt find anything. The idea is I have a PointF like (52.66, 60.11) and I want to draw an empty circle with this PointF as its center. I was trying to do with DrawEllipse but it does not care about the center! it is just a rectangle...I think some kind of conversion formula should be used?

Comment: Drawing an empty circle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the coordinates of the rectangle from the center and radius:

```
float x = center.X - radius;
float y = center.Y - radius;
float width = 2 * radius;
float height = 2 * radius;
graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, width, height);
```

Answer (score 1):

out of mind:

```
RectangleF circle2Rect(Point midPoint, float radius) {
   return new RectangleF(midPoint.X-radius,
                        midPoint.Y-radius,
                        radius*2,
                        radius*2); 
}
```

(This is not tested)
Use it to convert the parameter of the circle to a rectangle for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

if you draw an ellipse with same height and width you get a circle, if you need to know the Top-Left and Bottom-Right point's coordinates of the square in which your circle is drawn, it's quite banal knowing the middle point (center).